# Customize TFS Work Item Query

Tags: sql, tfs, wiql

I need to customize a Work Item query in a way that does not seem possible using the very limited WIQL.  I have a fairly standard query which needs changing slightly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><WorkItemQuery Version="1">
<TeamFoundationServer>http ://blah-
blah01:8080/tfs/blahcollection</TeamFoundationServer>
<TeamProject>Blah</TeamProject><Wiql>

SELECT 
[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority],[System.AreaPath],
[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity],[System.CreatedDate],[System.Id],
[System.WorkItemType],[System.Title],[System.CreatedBy],[System.State],
[System.AssignedTo],[System.ChangedDate],[BLAH.Category],[System.AreaId] 

FROM WorkItems

WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project 
and [System.WorkItemType] &lt;&gt; '' 
and [System.CreatedDate] &gt;= '2012-01-27T00:00:00.0000000' 
and [System.CreatedBy] &lt;&gt; 'blah' 
and not [System.State] contains 'Tested' 
and not [System.State] contains 'Released' 
and [System.State] &lt;&gt; 'Developed' 
and ([System.State] &lt;&gt; 'Closed' 
and not [System.State] contains 'Resolved') 
and [System.AssignedTo] in ('blah1', 'blah2', 'blah3') 

ORDER BY 

[System.WorkItemType], 
[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority], 
[System.AreaPath], 
[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity], 
[System.Id] desc, 
[System.AssignedTo] 

</Wiql></WorkItemQuery>
```

It should return the exactly same result as it does now, except that within the [System.AreaPath] column, items containing 'Foo' should appear first, items containing 'Bar' should appear next, and then the rest of the column should be ordered as normal.

This is straight forward enough in T-SQL but seemingly impossible using WIQL so I would appreciate any ideas or workarounds.

Something that may be relevant to the workaround is the unfortunate fact that the TFS instance sits on top of SQLExpress rather than full SQL Server (it was originally a proof of concept and is in the process of being replaced, there's nothing I can do about that at the moment but I still have to sort the query out)

Many thanks
Simon